# How to position arcs and lines correctly in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

I have this MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=2mm,scale=0.5]
    \draw (-4,-3) circle (4.5cm);
    \draw (-4,-3) circle (5.3cm);
    \draw (-2,-1) arc (0:-180:2);
    \draw (-2,-6) arc (0:180:2);
    \draw (-6,-3.5) -- (-2,-3.5);
    \draw (-4,-6) -- (-4,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Figure]

I want the middle figures to focus correctly on the two circles, and for the horizontal line to be touching both arcs, but without overlapping. Also that said horizontal line has the same length as the arcs (the vertical line seems to have the same height as the sum of the heights of the two arcs and the horizontal line), like this:

[image: Correct figure]

**Is there any way to do it without having to test the eye several times (but without programming, I am still learning to use the instructions that Tikz has)?**

Thanks!

Comment: You are using the wrong coordinate origin. Try starting with `\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=2mm,scale=0.5]
    \draw (-4,-3) circle (4.5cm);
    \draw (-4,-3) circle (5.3cm);
    \draw (-2,-1) arc (0:-180:2);
    \draw (-2,-5) arc (0:180:2);
    \draw (-6,-3) -- (-2,-3);
    \draw (-4,-5) -- (-4,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}` which only leaves the circles and the horizontal line length open. You might want to use clipping.

Comment: @TeXnician It helped me to align the figures to the middle, but that did not solve to put the horizontal line between the two arcs nor extend it to the width of the arches. There must be a formula of sines and cosines for the width, but I can not find it `:(`

Comment: your problem is the line width... If you add the half of the line width left and also the half right you will solve your problem (the circles-arcs are extended by half the linewidth outside and the half inside)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you need to know and to do according to my comment and not only:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\centering
We are starting from the base of our figure:

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
  \draw[line width =0.1pt] (0,0) circle (4.5cm);
  \draw[line width =0.1pt] ({-2 cm},{2. cm}) arc (180:360:2cm);
  \draw[line width =0.1pt] (-2cm,0)--(2cm,0);
  \draw[red,dashed,line width=0.1pt] (-2,-2.2)--(-2,2.2);
  \draw[red,dashed,line width=0.1pt] (2,-2.2)--(2,2.2);
  \node[text width =2.37cm] at (0,-2) {seems perfect without shifts};
\end{tikzpicture}

By adding a linewidth we will find out that we need shifts to fix the distances;

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    \draw[line width =0.1pt] (0,0) circle (4.5cm);
  \draw[line width =0.1pt] ({-2 cm},{2. cm}) arc (180:360:2cm);
  \draw[line width =0.1pt] (-2cm,0)--(2cm,0);
  \draw[line width =0.4cm,opacity=0.3,blue] (0,0) circle (4.5cm);
  \draw[line width =0.4cm,opacity=0.3,blue] ({-2 cm},{2. cm}) arc (180:360:2cm);
  \draw[line width =0.4cm,opacity=0.3,blue] (-2cm,0)--(2cm,0);
  \draw[red,dashed,line width=0.1pt] (-2,-2.2)--(-2,2.2);
    \draw[red,dashed,line width=0.1pt] (2,-2.2)--(2,2.2);
  \node[text width =2.37cm] at (0,-2) { now we need shifts};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
  \draw[line width =0.1pt] (0,0) circle (4.5cm);
  \draw[line width =0.1pt] (-1.8cm,{2. cm}) arc (180:360:{1.8cm});
  \draw[line width =0.1pt] (-2cm,0)--(2cm,0);
  \draw[red,line width=0.1pt] (2,-2.)--(2,2.2);
  \draw[line width =0.4cm,opacity=0.3,blue] (0,0) circle (4.5cm);
  \draw[line width =0.4cm,opacity=0.3,blue] ({-2cm +0.5\pgflinewidth},{2. cm}) arc (180:360:{2cm-0.2 cm});
  \draw[line width =0.4cm,opacity=0.3,blue] (-2cm,0)--(2cm,0);
  \draw[red,line width=0.1pt] (-2cm,-2.2cm)--(-2cm,2.2cm);
  \node[text width =2.37cm] at (0,-2) {reduced arc radius by 0.5*linewidth... also shifted x of its start by the same amount};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
  \draw[line width =0.1pt] (0,0) circle (4.5cm);
  \draw[line width =0.1pt] (-1.8cm,{2.2 cm}) arc (180:360:1.8cm);
  \draw[line width =0.1pt] (-2cm,0)--(2cm,0);
  \draw[red,line width=0.1pt] (2,-2.2)--(2,2.2);
  \draw[line width =0.4cm,opacity=0.3,blue] (0,0) circle (4.5cm);
  \draw[line width =0.4cm,opacity=0.3,blue] ({-2 cm+0.2 cm},{2 cm+0.2 cm}) arc (180:360:{2cm-0.2 cm});
  \draw[line width =0.4cm,opacity=0.3,blue] (-2cm,0)--(2cm,0);
  \draw[red,line width=0.1pt] (-2,-2.2)--(-2,2.2);
  \node[text width =2.37cm] at (0,-2) {shifted arc's y start by 0.5*linewidth};
\end{tikzpicture}

\pagebreak

After the shifts we adding the missing items of the figure:

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
  \draw[line width =0.4cm,opacity=0.3,blue] (0,0) circle (4.5cm);
  \draw[line width =0.4cm,opacity=0.3,blue] (0,0) circle (5.3cm);
  \draw[line width =0.4cm,opacity=0.3,blue] ({-2cm+0.2 cm},{2.2 cm}) arc (180:360:2cm-0.2 cm);
  \draw[line width =0.4cm,opacity=0.3,blue] ({-2 cm+0.2 cm},{-2.2 cm}) arc (180:0:2cm-0.2 cm);
  \draw[line width =0.4cm,opacity=0.3,blue] (-2cm,0)--(2cm,0);
  \draw[line width =0.4cm,opacity=0.3,blue] (0cm,-2.2cm)--(0cm,2.2cm);
  \draw[red,line width=0.1pt] (-2cm,-2.2cm)--(-2cm,2.2cm);
    \draw[red,line width=0.1pt] (2cm,-2.2cm)--(2cm,2.2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

But after scaling we will find out a problem\\(line width didn't scaled and leads to problems):

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
  \draw[line width =0.4cm,opacity=0.3,blue] (0,0) circle (4.5cm);
  \draw[line width =0.4cm,opacity=0.3,blue] (0,0) circle (5.3cm);
  \draw[line width =0.4cm,opacity=0.3,blue] ({-2cm+0.2 cm},{2.2 cm}) arc (180:360:2cm-0.2 cm);
  \draw[line width =0.4cm,opacity=0.3,blue] ({-2 cm+0.2 cm},{-2.2 cm}) arc (180:0:2cm-0.2 cm);
  \draw[line width =0.4cm,opacity=0.3,blue] (-2cm,0)--(2cm,0);
  \draw[line width =0.4cm,opacity=0.3,blue] (0cm,-2.2cm)--(0cm,2.2cm);
  \draw[red,line width=0.1pt] (-2cm,-2.2cm)--(-2cm,2.2cm);
    \draw[red,line width=0.1pt] (2cm,-2.2cm)--(2cm,2.2cm);
 \end{tikzpicture}

\pagebreak

So, we will fix scaling problem this way\\(adding a variable for scaling):

\def\sc{1.2}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width={0.4*\sc cm},scale=\sc]
  \draw[opacity=0.3,blue] (0,0) circle (4.5cm);
  \draw[opacity=0.3,blue] (0,0) circle (5.3cm);
  \draw[opacity=0.3,blue] ({-2cm+0.2 cm},{2.2 cm}) arc (180:360:{2cm-0.2cm});
  \draw[opacity=0.3,blue] ({-2 cm+0.2cm},{-2.2 cm}) arc (180:0:{2cm-0.2cm});
  \draw[opacity=0.3,blue] (-2cm,0)--(2cm,0);
  \draw[opacity=0.3,blue] (0cm,-2.2cm)--(0cm,2.2cm);
  \draw[red,line width=0.1pt] (-2cm,-2.2cm)--(-2cm,2.2cm);
    \draw[red,line width=0.1pt] (2cm,-2.2cm)--(2cm,2.2cm);
 \end{tikzpicture}


Now scaling is perfect too:

\def\sc{0.5}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width={0.4*\sc cm},scale=\sc]
  \draw[opacity=0.3,blue] (0,0) circle (4.5cm);
  \draw[opacity=0.3,blue] (0,0) circle (5.3cm);
  \draw[opacity=0.3,blue] ({-2cm+0.2 cm},{2.2 cm}) arc (180:360:{2cm-0.2 cm});
  \draw[opacity=0.3,blue] ({-2 cm+0.2 cm},{-2.2 cm}) arc (180:0:{2cm-0.2 cm});
  \draw[opacity=0.3,blue] (-2cm,0)--(2cm,0);
  \draw[opacity=0.3,blue] (0cm,-2.2cm)--(0cm,2.2cm);
  \draw[red,line width=0.1pt] (-2cm,-2.2cm)--(-2cm,2.2cm);
    \draw[red,line width=0.1pt] (2cm,-2.2cm)--(2cm,2.2cm);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Part of Output:

[image]

[image]

Comment: WOW! You are amazing. I tried to scale it and no problems! Put some description in your profile, like "Master of `TikZ`" `:)`.

Comment: hahaha... Glad that helped... I am not really master of tikz... I just have some experience on it but many people here (including percusse) knows much more things about it and have helped me really much.

Comment: The contribution of percussing was very useful also, because it showed me that not only are there certain commands (like `xshift`) that are used only in an environment (such as `axis` for example), but perhaps it was an error of mine not to mention the scale of the figure, so when you increase the scale in the percusse code, you went wild. But boy, did that help me! Thanks to both.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=3mm,scale=0.5]
\draw (0,0) circle (4.5cm);
\draw (0,0) circle (5.3cm);
\node[minimum size = 2cm,anchor=center] (a){};
\draw ([xshift=\pgflinewidth]a.north west) arc (180:360:2cm and 2cm-0.5\pgflinewidth) 
(a.west) -- (a.east)(a.north) -- (a.south)
([xshift=\pgflinewidth]a.south west) arc (180:0:2cm and 2cm-0.5\pgflinewidth);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Do you also know how to make a U with TikZ? **I think of the `arc` command but it is necessary to lengthen the part of the `arc` down** (and go from the northwest position of the centered figure by moving it to the right with the `xshift` command). Like the semicircle but more elongated. It must have the same height as the sum of the heights of the two arcs and the horizontal line, not counting the two circles.

Comment: @manooooh I couldn't picture it unfortunately. Just open another question as many as you like.