# How to make this letter as similar as possible in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, letters

I have this MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{vmargin}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\setpapersize{A4}
\setmargins{2.2cm}
{0.5cm}
{16.5cm}
{23.42cm}               
{30pt}
{1cm}
{0pt}
{2cm}   

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\large \thepage}
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{
\definecolor{micolor}{RGB}{191,14,50}
\def\sc{0.15}
\vspace{-8.85mm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep =0,outer sep=0,line width={0.6*\sc cm},scale=\sc]
    \draw[micolor,line width={0.8*\sc cm}] (23.6cm,2.45cm)--(23.6cm,-2.5cm); % Vertical line of "B"
    \draw[fill,micolor, line width={0.3*\sc cm}]
    (23.197cm,1.9cm)--
    (24.8cm,1.9cm) arc(90:-90:1.6cm and 0.943cm) --
    (23.35cm,0.015cm) --
    (23.35cm,-0.2cm) --
    (25.197cm,-0.2cm)  arc(-90:90:1.8cm and 1.3cm) --
    (23.197cm, 2.4cm);     % Upper belly of "B"
    \draw[fill,micolor,line width={0.3*\sc cm},rotate=180]
    (-23.197cm,1.9cm)--
    (-24.8cm,1.9cm) arc(90:-90:-1.8cm and 0.943cm) --
    (-23.35cm,0.015cm) --
    (-23.35cm,-0.2cm) --
    (-25.197cm,-0.2cm)  arc(-90:90:-2cm and 1.3cm) --
    (-23.197cm, 2.4cm);    % Lower belly of "B"
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
B
\end{document}
```

As you can see, I am trying to make the letter "B" as similar as possible to an already given one, but it does not remain identical to me.

[image: Letter B]

The image on the right is what I created, and the left is what it should look like.

**Keep in mind what you can not modify:**

- The scale of the letter.
- The thickness of each part.
- The `ymin` of the vertical line (`-2.5 cm`) and the `ymax` (`2.45 cm`). If by design issue you have to modify the width of the letter you can add or remove a few millimeters (that is, lengthen or shrink the bellies).

Please, can you help me improve that style?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the purpose of the exercise? Where does the left `B` comes from?

Comment: Off-topic: don't use `vmargin`. Use `geometry` or one of the other alternatives instead. Why don't you just use the relevant font to make the 'B' or include it as an image, if that's all you've got?

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek It comes from this [topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/412606/how-to-draw-manually-some-letters-in-tikz):

My problem is that I do not know how to handle the `arc` command correctly, that's why I asked for help.

Comment: @cfr If I use an image it is likely that in the final document I pixelee, something I do not want. That's why I decided to create it by hand, but I understand that it goes through something more of style than a question about `LaTeX`. I apologize

Comment: Are you aware of [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21548/121799). You can use `convert` to convert the pic to `pnm` and then `inkspace` to make a vector graphics from it or convert it to PSTricks ot TikZ. If you are confused about arcs, it might be better to ask a different question.

Comment: I doubt that there are perfect arcs. For a better approximation you would need Bezier curves instead.

Comment: It won't look fuzzy if you have a vector image. Are you saying you only have a raster B? I doubt that Ti*k*Z is the best way to do this, if it must be done. MetaPost might be more amenable. Essentially, the lines vary in width as if drawn with a pen. The effect is not very pronounced here, but it is still there. MetaPost (like MetaFont) has this concept, whereas Ti*k*Z does not. (At least, not out-of-the-box - for MP, the concept is fundamental.)

Comment: If this is just an exercise for `arc`, then I do not understand the unrelated `fancyhdr` stuff. Why can't you just use a sans-serif and probably bold `B`, scale it and color it red?

Comment: You can use potrace to get the vectorized version of this bitmap image. Here is an example of a more complicated image https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172336/drawing-roman-laurel-leaves-spqr-in-tikz

Comment: I will go in parts:


@marmot I applied the concepts you told me in the previous topic, but particularly this letter did not turn out well, and that's why I asked if a charitable soul offered to improve what I had done.


@cfr Something I read before about the vector image. If I'm honest, I do not need such complicated things; I prefer (for now, just for now) to handle the "crafts" and then refine myself with more advanced topics (I'm not in a `LaTeX` course learning how to use this or that thing, to be clear).

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek The `fanchyhdr` package and the footer are unnecessary, you're right. I should have taken it out of the MWE because it does not apply to this question.

@percusse The same thing I said to @cfr, I do not want to know that kind of solutions for now because I do not need them. It was about someone finishing the work "by hand" of doing the lyrics in TikZ simply.

Comment: I can only thank you for the time you have taken to write. **Thank you all!**

Comment: Lol, who do you think is a useful question? And the star who put it? It goes against what you told me about this question (and I have it very clear and I accept it)...

Comment: @manooooh I think it is a useful question because you can grow ducks in the B, please see my update. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for fun and because [marmots like ducks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/409029/121799), here are some arcs that give an OK fit to the letter. BTW, you should *not* call your macros `\sc` because that is already taken. And it is true what all the senior people like Heiko and cfr say. (`B.png` is just a screen shot of the left `B` of the question.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\definecolor{micolor}{RGB}{191,14,50}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (-8,0) {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{B.png}};
\fill[even odd rule,micolor]
(-2.1,-2.8) -- (-2.1,2.6) -- (0.85,2.6) arc (90:-70:1.25 and 1.28) 
arc (70:-90:1.54 and 1.5) --cycle
 (-1.2,-2) -- (-1.2,-0.3) -- (0.6,-0.3) arc(90:-90:0.8 and 0.85) --cycle
(-1.2,0.38) -- (-1.2,1.82) -- (0.6,1.82) arc(90:-90:0.6 and 0.72) --cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{B.png}};
\fill[even odd rule,blue,opacity=0.4]
(-2.1,-2.8) -- (-2.1,2.6) -- (0.85,2.6) arc (90:-70:1.25 and 1.28) 
arc (70:-90:1.54 and 1.5) --cycle
 (-1.2,-2) -- (-1.2,-0.3) -- (0.6,-0.3) arc(90:-90:0.8 and 0.85) --cycle
(-1.2,0.38) -- (-1.2,1.82) -- (0.6,1.82) arc(90:-90:0.6 and 0.72) --cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see in the overlay, the fit is at best OK. One difference to your drawing is that I draw the contours differently and that not all arcs run from -90 to 90.

And here is why redrawing some characters with Ti*k*Z might eventually be useful. You can shade them, vary the colors along the fill, and do lots of other things like hiding ducks in the letters.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzducks}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings,fadings}
\definecolor{micolor}{RGB}{191,14,50}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[xshift=0cm]
\shade[even odd rule,top color=micolor,bottom color=blue]
(-2.1,-2.8) -- (-2.1,2.6) -- (0.85,2.6) arc (90:-70:1.25 and 1.28) 
arc (70:-90:1.54 and 1.5) --cycle
 (-1.2,-2) -- (-1.2,-0.3) -- (0.6,-0.3) arc(90:-90:0.8 and 0.85) --cycle
(-1.2,0.38) -- (-1.2,1.82) -- (0.6,1.82) arc(90:-90:0.6 and 0.72) --cycle;
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=5cm]
\fill[even odd rule,micolor]
(-2.1,-2.8) -- (-2.1,2.6) -- (0.85,2.6) arc (90:-70:1.25 and 1.28) 
arc (70:-90:1.54 and 1.5) --cycle
 (-1.2,-2) -- (-1.2,-0.3) -- (0.6,-0.3) arc(90:-90:0.8 and 0.85) --cycle
(-1.2,0.38) -- (-1.2,1.82) -- (0.6,1.82) arc(90:-90:0.6 and 0.72) --cycle;
\node at(-0.4,1.1){\tikz[xscale=-1]{\duck}};
\fill[micolor] (-1.2,1.82) -- (-1.2,0.38) -- (0.5,0.38) -- 
(0.5,-0.3) -- (-2.1,-0.3) -- (-2.1,-1.82) -- cycle; 
\node at(-0.5,-1.2){\tikz[xscale=-1]{\duck}};
\fill[micolor] (-1.2,-0.3) -- (-1.2,-2) -- (0.5,-2) -- 
(0.5,-2.8) -- (-2.1,-2.8) -- (-2.1,-0.3) -- cycle; 
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's very good! As much as it is the most basic programming that includes, it helps me a lot. The only thing I had to add to the code was `\fill[xshift = 25.197cm, ...` since I have more letters and it was not positioned correctly in the right place. I wish I could put ducklings! It's for a college work... Regards

Comment: @manooooh Even though it does not produce a different result, I'd suggest that you put the thing in a scope `\begin{scope}[xshift=...] ... \end{scope}`.

Comment: I will consider that, dear @marmot `^-^`